# Get an Image of current location from WP8 map control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, winprt

I have an WP8 app which allows the user to send there location data to anybody in their contact list.
I need an option through which the user could send an image of their location via e-mail.

I have a map control in my app.

How do I get an image from the map control of the current location.

I don't want the screenshot of the entire app, just the location (or the map control).

Is there any way that I can do this from my app.
Please help me on this.

Comment: 1. The licenses of many map controls expressly prohibit taking screen shots of the map. 2. You can't add attachments to a mail message currently when using the Windows Phone sdk.

Comment: DVLUP competition? ;)